# How to hide and show markers on Google Map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, tags, location

I am a newbie in android coding and trying to get the grip of it. I am following tutorials and reading up on material online and books. I am starting to get a little confident hence moved onto more complicated tasks.

I am working with google maps and have managed to display my specified locations on the map upon launch.

```
//Making array businessNY global

public static ArrayList<LatLng> businessesNY;


//Creating a method showBNY to add given coordinates to the array and then add those arrayed coordinates on the map with given perimeter.  I call this method on my onCreate.

public static boolean showBNY(){
        businessesNY = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        businessesNY.add(new LatLng(40.741532, -73.989293));
        businessesNY.add(new LatLng(40.684281, -73.996159));

        for(LatLng bNY : businessesNY){ 
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
            .position(bNY)
            .title("New York Business")
        }

        return true;
    }
```

What I want to do next is create 2 or possibly 1 method for hiding these locations and or showing them if hidden and vice-versa. I was reading up on this and established you have to use `.setVisible(false)` to hide and `.setVisible(true);` to show. I want to allow the user to click a button to toggle on and same button to toggle off.

I cannot figure out how I can implement this, I have been working on it for long now and it is getting frustrating, I would really appreciate any help.

Could someone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Marker markers = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng)
                .title("MyPlace").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin)).draggable(true));
```

**On Click Event of your button**

Toggle Button

```
<ToggleButton 
  android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textOn="On"
  android:textOff="Off"
  android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Then only the handler method need to be defined in the Activity Java

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if(((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
          markers.setVisible(true); 
        // handle toggle on
    } else {
        markers.setVisible(false); 
       // handle toggle off
    }    
}
```

---

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put my values and variables in your code context, it will make it simpler for me to understand. I see you are adding markers to the map and then giving me a code to remove those set of markers. I do not understand how I can apply that to my code. =

Comment: My markers already display on the map on launch which I want, what I want to do next is give user the option to hide/unhide them on will.

Comment: @David The same I have suggested, iterate over that list and setVisible(false) on all of them

Comment: Could I ask what is the difference between Marker and LatLng

Comment: I was reading some material and they seem to use Marker as well and not LatLng.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me an example on how I can add markers to that list. I think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: maven I am sorry, I do not understand it. I cannot figure out how to add coordinates onto that array, I tried ArrayList<Marker> myMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>(40.741532, -73.989293); but that doesn't work.

Comment: The above code in the question is the complete code for adding markers to the map.

Comment: I want to allow the user to show and hide the locations, if I clear them the user will not be able to bring them back unless they restart the application.

Comment: so far I have 2 sets of coordinates I would like to add, given in the question above, I would increase them later on when I am more confident.

Comment: Looking at the code in my question, how and where would I imply the  for (Marker m : myMarkers) {
   m.setVisible(false);
 } I have a method to place markers, do I need to create another method for the code to hide. I do not want to remove, just temporarily hide as you stated. The example you have given, I am not sure where to add the coordinates on it. It might make it more clearer, if you can show me an example coordinate added to that please.

Comment: please remove `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
            .position(bNY)
            .title("New York Business")` and modify it to `Marker markers = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()`

Comment: Yes I removed that now, what shall I do next

Comment: now add `markers.setVisible(false);` on `Button Click`

Comment: the bNY in the for loop is underlined yellow, meaning it isn't being used.